# NiFi How to MergeContent into a one row csv

Tags: json, csv, apache-nifi

I am new to using Nifi and am having a problem merging two csv files into a single row csv.
I apologize if this question has been answered below. But, I have tried looking all over the internet but was unable to find a solution specific to my need.

So here is the problem:
I have data that is in Json format and I need to transform the data into csv and the file output should be a flat csv file.

I start with a Json Data that looks like this:

```
{"header": {"messageId": "xxx", "name":"xxx",..}, "content": {"TimeStamp":"xxx",..}}
```

I first split the json message into its header and content components and use ConvertRecord to convert the data from json to csv. I have it figured out upto this part.

The two csv records look like this:

[content section from json to csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiC3H.png)

[header section from json to csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KSjQ.png)

Then I use the MergeContent processor to merge the two csv data, to hopefully get a single csv data with the header and content data in one row (with the header being in row 1 and the values in row 2). However, on merging the contents I get this
[merge results from MergeContent processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXhfe.png)

As you can see, the headers from the 'header' header section is in line 1 and the headers from the 'content' section is in line 3 and the values are in line 2 and 4 respectively. But, what I want is both the headers of the 'header' section and 'content' section to be in line 1 and the values of both sections to be in line 2.

Is my approach to solving the problem incorrect? Is there a better approach to this problem? Also, what can I do to correct this current approach to get my desired result?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a different approach.  Imagine we had JSON that looked like:

```
{
  "part1": {
    "A": "A1",
    "B": "B1"
  },
  "part2": {
    "X": "X1",
    "Y": "Y1"
  }
}
```

and what you wanted was CSV that looked like:

```
A,B,X,Y
A1,B1,X1,Y1
```

then we could solve this puzzle by reworking the original JSON to a new JSON description that looks like:

```
{
  "A":"A1",
  "B":"B1",
  "X":"X1",
  "Y":"Y1"
}
```

we can then use our JSON to CSV converter which should produce the format you are looking for.

To transform the original JSON to our desired JSON we could use the `JoltTransformJSON` processor.  An example specification might be:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "part1": {
          "*": "&"
        },
        "part2": {
          "*": "&"
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I was dabbling with the JoltTransformer processor earlier. I will try what you suggested and update you with the results.